# SQL if statment

Tags: sql

I have this SQL query:

```
Select 
   * from dbo.Users 
WHERE 
   numOfScans == 0 feedback >= {0} 
AND 
   feedback <= {1} 
ORDER BY 
   lastScan ASC
```

It bring me all the users that the `numOfScans` is zero.
I have another case that if this `SELECT` bring me zero results so i don't want to use `numOfScans`, something like:

```
Select 
  * from dbo.Users 
WHERE 
  feedback >= {0} AND feedback <= {1} 
ORDER BY 
  lastScan ASC
```

It's possible to do this in the same query? Or I need a new query for that?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. Formatted text please, not images.

Comment: (OT) A `{0}` suggests that you are using String.Format to build your query. Please use parameters instead - look up on Sql Injection

Comment: `numOfScans == 0 feedback` that looks like odd SQL syntax to me.

Comment: It would be awesome if you could show 15 lines of sample data, and explain the results you are expecting to see in your query based on those 15 lines of sample data.

Comment: Please improve your question title. I tried to fix the spelling in the title but the system wouldn't allow "SQL if statement".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could phrase this using a union:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Users 
WHERE numOfScans == 0 AND feedback BETWEEN {0} AND {1}
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Users 
WHERE
    feedback BETWEEN {0} AND {1} AND
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Users
     WHERE numOfScans == 0 AND feedback BETWEEN {0} AND {1}) = 0
ORDER BY lastScan;
```

The basic idea here is that if the first half of the union returns any records, then the second half would be empty set, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the result of first query in the temp variable and check if

```
@temp==0 then
Select * from dbo.Users 
WHERE feedback >= {0} AND feedback <= {1} 
ORDER BY lastScan ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Option:

using stored procedure

```
create procedure  procsample  @first varchar(10),@second varchar(10) as
begin
  declare @sql varchar(10);

    Select @sql= count(1) from dbo.Users 
     WHERE numOfScans == 0 feedback >= @first AND feedback <= @second;


   if(@sql=0)

   Select * from dbo.Users 
   WHERE feedback >= @first AND feedback <= @second
   ORDER BY lastScan ASC;

   else

   Select * from dbo.Users 
   WHERE numOfScans == 0 feedback >= @first AND feedback <= @second
   ORDER BY lastScan ASC;

end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try approach with exists statement.
It will apply filter only if those records are exist

```
Select * from dbo.Users
WHERE feedback >= {0} AND feedback <= {1} AND
(numOfScans = 0 OR NOT Exists(
        Select * from dbo.Users 
        WHERE numOfScans == 0)
)
 ORDER BY lastScan ASC
```